# ACF Images If/else

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

```
<div class="postthumbnail">

<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('usercrop'), 'full'); ?>
<img class="post-thumbnail img-responsive postpic" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(get_field('usercrop')) ?>" />

</div>
```

How do I make it, so it only echoes if there is something in the field (usercrop)? I guess I should use If/else? Right now, it echoes the title of the page. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
<div class="postthumbnail">
<?php 
    $usercrop = get_field('usercrop');
    if ($usercrop) { 
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('usercrop'), 'full'); ?>
        <img class="post-thumbnail img-responsive postpic" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(get_field('usercrop')) ?>" />
    <?php }
?>
</div>
```

It checks the field and only displays the HTML if `get_field('usercrop')` returns something